# infinitesimal jackknife confidence intervals for bagged learners are NOT prediction intervals, right?

Tags: r, confidence-interval, random-forest, prediction-interval

[Wager, Hastie, and Efron](http://www.jmlr.org/papers/volume15/wager14a/wager14a.pdf) present a method for computing confidence intervals for RF predictions.

Confidence intervals have to do with the variability of the expectation, not the expectation of the variability.  A prediction interval is the sum of these two things.

But suddenly I'm not so sure:  there is a package on CRAN -- `RFinfer` -- that seems to treat the output of Wager et al.'s method as though they are prediction intervals.  See the first figure under the "Compare Model Predictions" subheading, here:

https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/RFinfer/vignettes/RFinfer-examples.html

> In Wager et al.'s paper, they explicitly state that
>
> The goal of out paper is to study the sampling variance of bagged
>   learners $$ V(x) = Var\left[\hat\theta^\infty(x)\right] $$

Where they had defined

$$
\hat\theta^\infty(x) = E_*[t(x, Z^*_1, ..., Z^*_n)]
$$

where the $Z$ are input data, the $^*$ indicates a bootstrap sample, and $t(x)$ is the prediction of a base learner, (typically a tree) evaluated at $x$

**TL;DR:** that looks like the variance of an expectation.  For standard errors, not standard deviations.  Take the square root and multiply it by 1.96 (asymptotically) and you get a 95% confidence interval, NOT a 95\% prediction interval.  Right?  That R package's vignette might be leading people astray?  Or am I the one confused?

If I'm not mistaken, a prediction interval would take Wager et al.'s estimate, and add it to the variance of the prediction error (not the out-of-bag error).

Comment: Not answering your question, but just FYI I have never gotten those infinitesimal jackknife estimators to work. Meaning, they have not for me ever gotten close to the nominal coverage level whenever I try them out on a problem of moderate size or difficulty.

Comment: @guy have you been treating them as prediction or confidence intervals?

Comment: I treat them as confidence intervals because that is what they are intended to be.

Comment: That's what I thought!